# How-to submit to Artist controller, update method instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Artist conroller, edit method looks like this

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

In the view (artists/edit.html.erb), I have:

```
<%= form_for(@artist) do |f| %>

  <ul>
    <li class="clearfix">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>

  <%= image_submit_tag('update.png', :class => 'submit') %>    
<% end %>
```

However, when rendered. The form element submits to the user controller, update method (i.e. ).

How do I make it submit to the artist controller, update method instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to change the form_for parameters :

```
<%= form_for(@artist, :url => edit_user_path(@artist)) do |f| %>

  <ul>
    <li class="clearfix">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>

  <%= image_submit_tag('update.png', :class => 'submit') %>    
<% end %>
```

Cf http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

---

Also, are you sure your @artist points to @user ? I think you meant, in your controller :

```
@artist = User.find....
```

Comment: Hi Marcel, yes you are right. Was a typo. Supposed to be @artist = User.find(params[:id]). Ill try changing the url params as you suggested

Comment: Thanks Marcel. Works with: <%= form_for(@artist, :url => artist_path(@artist)) do |f| %>